# In what applications caching does not give any advantage?

Tags: caching, embedded

Our professor asked us to think of an embedded system design where caches cannot be used to their full advantage. I have been trying to find such a design but could not find one yet. If you know such a design, can you give a few tips?

Comment: Start with what *is* the "full advantage" (of the cache/a cache); how can that be minimized/degraded? What overhead/requirements does a cache have that is practical on a [larger] CPU but might not be practical on a microcontroller?

Answer (score 5):

Caches exploit the fact data (and code) exhibit [locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

So an embedded system wich does not exhibit locality, will not benefit from a cache.

#### Example:

An embedded system has 1MB of memory and 1kB of cache.
If this embedded system is accessing memory with short jumps it will stay long in the same 1kB  area of memory, which could be successfully cached.
If this embedded system is jumping in different distant places inside this 1MB and does that frequently, then there is no locality and cache will be used badly.

Also note that depending on architecture you can have different caches for data and code, or a single one.

#### More specific example:

If your embedded system spends most of its time accessing the same data and (e.g.) running in a tight loop that will fit in cache, then you're using cache to a full advantage.
If your system is something like a database that will be fetching random data from any memory range, then cache can not be used to it's full advantage. (Because the application is not exhibiting locality of data/code.)

#### Another, but weird example

Sometimes if you are building safety-critical or mission-critical system, you will want your system to be highly predictable. Caches makes your code execution being very unpredictable, because you can't predict if a certain memory is cached or not, thus you don't know how long it will take to access this memory. Thus if you disable cache it allows you to judge you program's performance more precisely and calculate worst-case execution time. That is why it is common to disable cache in such systems.

Comment: I want to add that the 1kB does not have to be consecutive. "... jumping in distant places inside this 1MB ..." is confusing. The "distance" between memory locations doesn't matter. What matters is how often the same memory location is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you background is but I suggest to read about what the "volatile" keyword does in the c language.

Comment: Volatile data bypasses cache, so it's not used

Comment: Er... no, that's not what `volatile` means at all.

Comment: To expand on Jonathan's comment, `volatile` just tells the compiler to always access the location directly "from memory" and in the same order as in the source code. The compiler does not really know about cache though, which is transparent to the CPU. Special techniques are required to prevent caching.

Comment: @other commenters so indeed volatile might give an idea of when caches aren't a big advantage. Writing code that has to bypass caches doesn't really utilize cache well

Comment: @theran it also tells the optimizer that it has to read the value every time even if the compiler can find no writes between two reads. That has nothing to do with caching but a lot to do with memory mapped HW

Comment: @RuneFS, `volatile` ensures that the compiler does its part right, but it doesn't get the whole way there to properly accessing memory mapped hardware. You still have to ensure that the hardware doesn't transparently cache the "memory" access.

Comment: volatile has nothing to do with bypassing the cache.  All it does is say do not keep this in a register.  Normally volatile is used for shared variables and most often hardware access, so it may have a feel that it bypasses the cache.  To complete the circle, some other code or individual has to insure that that address goes through the cache if a hardware register/memory is what the pointer/data is after, the compiler has nothing to do with it.  All the compiler is supposed to do is not optimize out the read/write from/to the memory/io interface. the compiler is unable to do more on its own

Comment: @dwelch Indeed, special instructions are needed to bypass the cache when needed for memory mapped devices. Volatile is also necessary to not used the "cached" values in registers, but that is another story and not contributing to the question asked, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how a cache works.  For example if you want to defeat a cache, depending on the cache, you might try having your often accessed data at 0x10000000, 0x20000000, 0x30000000, 0x40000000, etc.  It takes very little data at each location to cause cache thrashing and a significant performance loss.

Another one is that caches generally pull in a "cache line"  A single instruction fetch may cause 8 or 16 or more bytes or words to be read.  Any situation where on average you use a small percentage of the cache line before it is evicted to bring in another cache line, will make your performance with the cache on go down.

In general you have to first understand your cache, then come up with ways to defeat the performance gain, then think about any real world situations that would cause that.  Not all caches are created equal so there is no one good or bad habit or attack that will work for all caches.  Same goes for the same cache with different memories behind it or a different processor or memory interface or memory cycles in front of it.  You also need to think of the system as a whole.

EDIT:

Perhaps I answered the wrong question.  not...full advantage.  that is a much simpler question.  In what situations does the embedded application have to touch memory beyond the cache (after the initial fill)?  Going to main memory wipes out the word full in "full advantage". IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Caching does not offer an advantage, and is actually a hindrance, in controlling memory-mapped peripherals. Things like coprocessors, motor controllers, and UARTs often appear as just another memory location in the processor's address space. Instead of simply storing a value, those locations can cause something to happen in the real world when written to or read from.

Cache causes problems for these devices because when software writes to them, the peripheral doesn't immediately see the write. If the cache line never gets flushed, the peripheral may never actually receive a command even after the CPU has sent hundreds of them. If writing 0xf0 to 0x5432 was supposed to cause the #3 spark plug to fire, or the right aileron to tilt down 2 degrees, then the cache will delay or stop that signal and cause the system to fail.

Similarly, the cache can prevent the CPU from getting fresh data from sensors. The CPU reads repeatedly from the address, and cache keeps sending back the value that was there the first time. On the other side of the cache, the sensor waits patiently for a query that will never come, while the software on the CPU frantically adjusts controls that do nothing to correct gauge readings that never change.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to almost complete answer by Halst, I would like to mention one additional case where caches may be far from being an advantage. If you have multiple-core SoC where all cores, of course, have own cache(s) and depending on how program code utilizes these cores - caches can be very ineffective. This may happen if ,for example, due to incorrect design or program specific (e.g. multi-core communication) some data block in RAM is concurrently used by 2 or more cores.